# Cannot save array to CSV file from EvaluationMonitor[]

Tags: mathematical-optimization, files-and-directories

Here is my Mathematica function.

```
fourVertEnrgy[x11_, x12_,x13_, x14_, x21_, x22_, x23_, x24_, x31_, x32_, x33_, x34_, x41_, x42_, x43_, x44_]:=
1 + 2x11 x12 + 2x11 x13+ 2x11 x14+2x12 x13 + 2 x12 x14+ 2x13 x14 -x11 -x12 -x13 - x14 +
1+2x21 x22+2x21 x23+2x21 x24+ 2x22 x23+ 2x22 x24+ 2x23 x24 - x21 -x22 -x23-x24 + 
1 + 2x31 x32 + 2x31 x33 + 2x31 x34 + 2x32 x33 + 2 x32 x34 + 2 x33 x34 -x31 -x32- x33-x34 + 
1+2x41 x42 + 2x41 x43 +2 x41 x44 + 2x42 x43 + 2x42 x44 + 2x43 x44 - x41-x42 -x43 -x44 + 
1 + 2x11 x21 + 2x11 x31 + 2x11 x41 + 2x21 x31 + 2x21 x41 +2x31 x41 -x11-x21-x31-x41+
1+2x12 x22 + 2x12 x32 + 2x12 x42 + 2x22 x32 + 2x22 x42 + 2x32 x42 -x12 -x22-x32-x42 + 
1+2x13 x23 + 2x13 x33 + 2x13 x43 + 2x23 x33 + 2x23 x43 + 2x33 x43 -x13-x23-x33-x43+
1+2x14 x24 + 2x14 x34 + 2x14 x44+ 2x24 x34 + 2x24 x44 + 2x34 x44 -x14-x24 -x34 -x44;
```

I am trying to find the minima using Simulated Annealing.

```
destFile=OpenWrite["/home/shehab/Documents/shehab-isi/quantum-shehab/docs/presentations/lucas-gi-algo/values-"<>DateString[]]
i=0; list={{0,9999999}}; 
NMinimize[{fourVertEnrgy[x11, x12,x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, x41, x42, x43,x44],
x11\[Element]Integers,x12\[Element]Integers,x13\[Element]Integers, x14\[Element]Integers,x21\[Element]Integers, x22\[Element]Integers, x23\[Element]Integers,x24\[Element]Integers, x31\[Element]Integers, x32\[Element]Integers,x33\[Element]Integers, x34\[Element]Integers, x41\[Element]Integers, x42\[Element]Integers, x43\[Element]Integers,x44\[Element]Integers,
0<=x11<=1,0<=x12<=1,0<=x13<=1,0<=x14<=1,0<=x21<=1,0<=x22<=1,0<=x23<=1,0<=x24<=1,0<=x31<=1,0<=x32<=1,0<=x33<=1,0<=x34<=1, 0<=x41<=1, 0<=x42<=1,0<=x43<=1,0<=x44<=1},{x11, x12,x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, x41, x42, x43, x44},
Method->"SimulatedAnnealing",EvaluationMonitor:>Join[list,{{i++,fourVertEnrgy[x11, x12,x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, x41, x42, x43, x44]}}]]
Export[destFile,list,"CSV"] 
Close[destFile]
```

I am using EvaluationMonitor[] to store the function value against the step number for all the steps in a CSV file. But the file only has $0, 9999999$ when the computation is done. Did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues: You don't have to `OpenWrite` a file when you use `Export`. `Export` will do everything for you. `OpenWrite` is for situations where you want to do low-level file operations. You can use `Element[{a,b,c},..]` to say say that `a,b,c` should be `Integers`. When you want to store values of `EvaluationMonitor` it is maybe easier to use `Sow` and `Reap`.

```
{result, monitor} = 
  Reap@NMinimize[{fourVertEnrgy[x11, x12, x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, 
      x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, x41, x42, x43, x44], 
     Element[{x11, x12, x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, x24, x31, x32, 
           x33, x34, x41, x42, x43, x44}, Integers], 
        0 <= x11 <= 1, 0 <= x12 <= 1, 0 <= x13 <= 1, 0 <= x14 <= 1, 
        0 <= x21 <= 1, 0 <= x22 <= 1, 0 <= x23 <= 1, 0 <= x24 <= 1, 
        0 <= x31 <= 1, 0 <= x32 <= 1, 0 <= x33 <= 1, 0 <= x34 <= 1, 
        0 <= x41 <= 1, 0 <= x42 <= 1, 0 <= x43 <= 1, 0 <= x44 <= 1}, 
      {x11, x12, x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, 
     x41, x42, 
        x43, x44}, Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing", 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[fourVertEnrgy[x11, x12, x13, x14, x21, x22, x23, 
        x24, x31, x32, x33, x34, x41, x42, x43, x44]]];
list = Table[{i, monitor[[1, i]]}, {i, Length[monitor[[1]]]}];
Export["output.csv", list]
```

Comment: thanks. When I run the code in the 'Out' dialogue (i.e. removing the semi-colons) it shows the global minima 0 but in the file the lowest value is 4. Any hint?